# Scraper not returning results from dynamic webpage

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, steam, scrape

I'm trying to scrape all update notes from https://store.steampowered.com/newshub/app/1145360. I identified the update notes with class "eventcalendar_CalendarRow_398u2" and wrote the code like such:

```
updatenotes = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"eventcalendar_CalendarRow_398u2"})
for updatenote in updatenotes:
```

but when I try to scrape, it doesn't return any result, which I think is due to the dynamic nature of the website. I'm using Selenium to scroll down completely before I start scraping, but it's not working. Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
driver.get('https://store.steampowered.com/newshub/app/1145360')
scroll_pause_time = 1
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    updatenotes=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.eventcalendar_CalendarRow_398u2")
    print(len(updatenotes))
    for updatenote in updatenotes:
        print(updatenote.text)
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        # If heights are the same it will exit the function
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Comment: Thanks, this is cool but it seems like when I'm trying to scrape from a page (for some other game) that has a lot of entries, it only returns values at the bottom of the page, not the whole page. I think scrolling works a bit awkwardly on the page, maybe that's the problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok try this one out.

Comment: So this is code to scroll to bottom, right? The problem is that, once you scroll down to the bottom and then scrape, the code only scrapes data that is at the bottom of the page, but not data at the top of the website.

Comment: And If I don't scroll, I only get data from the top. So basically it seems like the scraper is only able to scrape what is near the screen is showing, which is weird.